# Create and send a NDEFMessage similar to a passport chip

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, contactless-smartcard, hce

I'm using and testing this library http://jmrtd.org/ that is a great work. 
I learned how to read and handle all the data from a passport chip.
Now my next step it will be create a simple android app for sending a NdefMessage that I have to read with the same library. 
I guess that the most simple way to reach this is creating a NdefMessage that simulates the structure of a passport chip. 
Is this possible? 
Do you have any advice or experiences on that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. Passports do not use NDEF to store data. Instead they use an application protocol specific to chip-based machine redable travel documents as defined in ICAO 9303.

A bit off-scope to your question:
Starting with Android 4.4, Google introduced host-based card emulation (HCE). (A similar functionality has been integrated into CyanogenMod since 9.1.) With HCE, you could emulate the eMRTD application according to ICAO 9303 by implementing the ISO 7816-4 APDU based protocol.

Comment: Hi @Michael Roland, 
I having problem with AA, I am using jmrtd library and when decrypt message from eMRTD, I initialize java Cipher like this `cipher = Cipher.getInstance(pubKey.getAlgorithm())`, but it is failed. 
Do I need to add cryptographic mode such as (NONE/ECB/CBC...) and padding when initialize cipher?

Comment: @neo Please [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a new question. Please don't hijack other people's questions.